# OSX- main thread is in wait how to get intrrupt pipe response

Tags: multithreading, macos, network-programming, kernel, kernel-extension

I am developing a device driver on mac. my question is how can we make a device request asynchronous to synchronous. like i send a send encapsulated command to device and get it response using get encapsulated command after getting a notification on interrupt pipe. so how can i make my thread will wait until all above request is not completed (both send and get) . but the function from get encap is called is a virtual function and called by upper layer. so if i process a wait in that virtual function  then i am not able to get response till my tread is in waiting process. 
please help me to resolve this problem.

thnks in advance.

Comment: Please Reply as soon as possible

Comment: possible duplicate of [Thread should wait for commplete the device request in kext programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20744836/thread-should-wait-for-commplete-the-device-request-in-kext-programming)

Comment: i previous question i have called function from other thread and main thread is free for response but the present time function is called by upper layer to set packetfilter so its a main thread. and the response we get at interrupt pipe is also called when main thread is free. so how to tackle that situation. please give an example or site where i can found the solution

Comment: There is no "main thread" in the kernel?

Comment: sorry i called my code thread as main thread. when i called USBSetMulticastFilter from my code IOLockSleepDeadline works fine. but when USBSetMulticastFilter called by upper layer driver wait for maximum wating time and then forward because it is a statistics call so need to wait for complete the event

Comment: please rply as soon as posible

Comment: code running in constructor is single threaded (per kext).
so how can i put thread in sleep and get response form interrupt pipe.
help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: How about posting some code? It's not clear from your description at all what you're trying to do.

Comment: bool class::USBSetPacketFilter() { IOReturn Value; .... ................. value = send_Encasulated_command(* of structure, length); IOLocksleepdeadline(x, y, z, w); global variable which is updated when get_Encap is completed. if (Value == IOSuccess &&XVZ == true) return true; else return false } } in other function to readinterrupt pipe pipe->Read(mMemDes,&m_CommInfo,NULL); in call back function we check it is a device response or not then we call get_encapsulated function to complete the request and IOLockwakeup(x,y,z) to revoke the thread.

Comment: You might want to edit the question with properly formatted code and a  more detailed explanation. I still don't see how the question is any different from the other question of yours I answered.

Answer (score 0):

**

```
bool class::USBSetPacketFilter() 
{ 
IOReturn Value
.... ................. 
value = send_Encasulated_command(* of structure, length);
 IOLocksleepdeadline(x, y, z, w);
 global variable which is updated when get_Encap is completed. 
if (Value == IOSuccess &&XVZ == true) 
return true;
 else return false 
}
```

** 
in other function to readinterrupt pipe

```
pipe->Read(mMemDes,&**m_CommInfo**,NULL);
```

### in m_CommInfo call back function we check it is a device response or not then we call get_encapsulated function to complete the request and IOLockwakeup(x,y,z) to revoke the thread

.

### but when the upper layer call USBSetPacketFilter(). MY code stuck on IOLocksleepdeadline till the time out is not completed. so thread did not go to read interputpipe.